# How do I repackage certificates into pkcs #7 certificate using bouncy castle?

Tags: java, cryptography, x509certificate, bouncycastle, pkcs#7

I have root, intermediate and end entity certificates and, I want to package it in pkcs # 7 format using bouncy castle.
How can I do it?

Comment: What have you tried? This isn't a code writing service - there are plenty of paid ones available online.

Comment: I do not have any clue. And I am NOT asking for code writing service. I am searching for the idea or resource which I can implement myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the very first, you have to read latest RFC on PKCS#7/CMS. Please click on this [RFC Link](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5652) to read.

Now to fulfill your objective, use bouncycastle. You need to generate [CMSSignedData data](https://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/pkixdocs1.4/org/bouncycastle/cms/CMSSignedData.html). For that, you need to prepare private key and Certificate chain. Here, I am going to assume, you already have those. Now prepare [CMSProcessableByteArray](https://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/pkixdocs1.4/org/bouncycastle/cms/CMSProcessableByteArray.html).

```
CMSProcessableByteArray msg = new CMSProcessableByteArray("Hello World".getBytes());
```

Now, prepare the store with the List of certificates.

```
Store certs = new JcaCertStore(certList);
```

Then declare [CMSSignedDataGenerator](https://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/pkixdocs1.5on/org/bouncycastle/cms/CMSSignedDataGenerator.html) and add signerInfo and certificates.

```
CMSSignedDataGenerator gen = new CMSSignedDataGenerator();
gen.addSignerInfoGenerator(new JcaSignerInfoGeneratorBuilder(......));
gen.addCertificates(certs);
```

Then generate CMSSignedData with CMSSignedDataGenerator and CMSProcessableByteArray.

```
CMSSignedData cmsData = gen.generate(msg, true);
```

Finally write the the byte array of the CMSSignedData (`cmsSignedData.getEncoded()`) to a location with .p7b file extension. Open the file to see the certificate chain.

Comment: Thanks @Saqib for a reference, I used JcaCertStore and was able to repackage the certificate.

Comment: Hey @Saqib Rezwan, can you please look at this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30202188/how-to-reformat-pkcs-7-certificate?noredirect=1)?? Let me know, if you have any thought on that. Thanks.

Comment: Hey @Artjob, can you please take a look at this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30202188/how-to-reformat-pkcs-7-certificate?noredirect=1)? Thanks.

Comment: Showing "Page not found" and "question was removed from stack overflow............."

Comment: I am sorry... I just found out that the page was removed by stackoverflow. Sorry for inconvenience. The question was realted to this current question. I have some issue in formatting new PKCS # 7. I mean after repackaging the PKCS # 7 certificate. The certificate description comes in just one line, usualy thats not the case. Please let me know, if you have any thought on that. Thanks in advance.