# Convert PEM to PKCS7 (Java)

Tags: java, certificate, pem, pkcs#7

I have a List of Byte arrays (representing each certificate from a chain), in PEM format, and I would like to know if there's a way to convert these to a unique PKCS7 formatted String, in Java.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Yes, it is possible using bouncycastle. What have you tried?

Comment: Only this http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=org.bouncycastle.util.io.pem.PemWriter (example 5)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I repackage certificates into pkcs #7 certificate using bouncy castle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29638061/how-do-i-repackage-certificates-into-pkcs-7-certificate-using-bouncy-castle)

Comment: That is the case where you have the private key, which I don't have.

Comment: You are right, it is not exactly the same. See my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an example to build a PKCS#7 file using a `X509Certificate[]` array based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29671316/6371459). It does not require the private key

```
//Export a certificate list to PKCS#7
public static byte[] exportCertificatesAsPkcs7(X509Certificate certs[]) throws Exception {

    List certList = new ArrayList();
    for (X509Certificate certificate: certs){
        certList.add(new X509CertificateHolder(certificate.getEncoded()));
    }
    Store certStore = new JcaCertStore(certList);

    CMSProcessableByteArray msg = new CMSProcessableByteArray("Hello World".getBytes());
    CMSSignedDataGenerator    gen = new CMSSignedDataGenerator(); 
    gen.addCertificates(certStore);
    CMSSignedData data = gen.generate(msg, "BC"); 
    return data.getEncoded();

}
```